# Переносы при выводе из БД

Tags: php, sql

Если в бд занести текст с переносом строки, например:

> тест
>
> ещё тест

то "**ещё тест**" идёт в самое начало, а нужно, чтобы было в span

[image]

Comment: развеселый у вас что скрин, что вопрос.

Comment: Дык весь текст и так заключён в <span>. На странице ведь отображается нормально? ;-)

Comment: @orkaan, да. Но если в БД сделать перенос, вот как на скрине "фыв", то текст "фыв" улетает.

Comment: не понятна суть вопроса) как mysql связано с html? у вас на сайте криво отображается или при просмотре исходника страницы?

Comment: @ModaL, ведь это вывод того, что есть в базе. Если вам нужен "красивый исходный текст HTML", то с БД, как сказал @thunder, это никак не связано. Вам нужно понимать "на каком вы уровне вложенности тегов" и в зависимости от этого формировать нужный сдвиг.

Comment: Текст в базе "не знает" ничего о том, как он будет использован. 
Ваше право вторую отбить вторую строчку в записи вправо пробелами/табами, но зачем?! Это ни на что не влияет в браузере, а раз вы читаете этот фрагмент из базы, значит и на качестве ваших исходников оно тоже не отражается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак. Только добавлять табы. 
Фав улетел потому, что перед ним нет табов

Answer (score 0):

Если ты имел про то что когда выводишь из БД и выводит все в одну строчку, то вот прекрасный скрипт на php `nl2br` подробнее о нем сможешь прочитать здесь [ССЫЛКА](http://www.php.su/nl2br) использовать его сможешь так: `$a = nl2br($sqlinject[text]);`